# Where and how can I check to which questions I raised flag?

Tags: support, flagging

I raised flag to some questions on SU, but later I really didn't find where to check to which questions I raised flag and what moderators did with it. Like I want to know whether the moderators closed it or not? or kind of activity they did on it..

Answer (score 2):

Go to [your user profile](https://superuser.com/users/113701/user113701), and click on the number where it says "helpful flags". This will show you your previous flags, and whether the post was deleted.

Comment: [Direct link](http://superuser.com/users/flag-summary/113701).